# Auto Save in atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor

I searching for auto-save on every edit feature in atom editor but i did't found it , The default auto-save is not enough , is there any way to change default auto-save setting if possible?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [autosave-onchange](https://atom.io/packages/autosave-onchange).